# Creo propiedades en un Form y no los veo desde otro Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Dentro del fichero frmPruebas.cs he creado una propiedad:

```
public partial class frmPruebas : Form
{
    private String mURL;

    public string MURL
    {
        set
        {
            mURL = value;
        }
    }

...
}
```

Y cuando trato de llamarla desde otro Form, no tiene acceso:

```
private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form objPruebas = new frmPruebas();

    objPruebas.MURL = txtURL.Text;
    objPruebas.ShowDialog();
}
```

Y me dice que `FORM` no contiene una definición para `MURL`.

¿Sabéis por qué puede ser?

Comment: Estas creando un nuevo frmPruebas y lo estas asignando a un Form, deberías asignarlo a un frmPruebas, te quedaría de la siguiente manera, frmPruebas objPruebas = new frmPruebas();. Te aconsejo cambiar el String por string

Answer (score 4):

El problema está con esta sentencia:

```
Form objPruebas = new frmPruebas();
```

Aunque creas un objeto de tipo `frmPruebas`, lo asignas a una variable de tipo `Form`, que no tiene una propiedad `MURL`.

Si cambias la sentencia a:

```
var objPruebas = new frmPruebas();
```

...o:

```
frmPruebas objPruebas = new frmPruebas();
```

... funcionará correctamente.

Comment: Pequeña ayuda, ya que aún eres nuevo en el uso del sitio: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal en tu caso es crear un metodo publico dentro de formulario que permita modificar la propiedas que desees, de esta manera podras modificar cada instancia de ese formulario desde fuera llamando a ese metodo de una manera sencilla y controlada.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta la declaración "set" de la propiedad MURL. Algo así deberías tener

```
public partial class frmPruebas : Form
{
    private String mURL;

    public string MURL
    {
        get
        {
            return mURL;
        }
        set
        {
            mURL = value;
        }

    }
    /* Resto del código */
```

}